# How to locate where a ball hits the ground?

Tags: projectile, measurements

I want to locate a small ball when it hits the ground before it rolls or bounces. Consider a robotic gun fires a plastic pebble at an angle like artillery. The ball flies in the air about 0.5 seconds until it lands. Distance from the location instrument is 1 meter. What is the best way to identify the position of the fallen ball down to several mm?

The signal should not necessarily be processed in real-time. Post-processing is also ok.

I was playing with an idea of an augmented reality game like [an artillery game](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artillery_game) where a robotic gun fires a round pebble and based on the position of the hit the program changes the environment or just checks hit or miss. It is played somewhere in a park where wind and terrain are random. Round pebbles have low precision and launch from the barrel with a bit randomized direction, see paintball and airsoft.

Currently I have the following ideas:

1. Identify the trajectory by using ultrasound
2. Identify the trajectory by using a radio transmitter in the ball
3. Identify the trajectory by using a camera

But I am not sure which approach is cheap and precise enough and maybe there are better approaches, that do not need a trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the standard equations of motion. If the ball is in the air for 0.5 seconds then it spent 0.25 seconds going up and 0.25 seconds going down. The y-velocity of the projectile at its highest point is 0. For a body dropping from rest we can write  $$dy = v_{y0} +\frac{1}{2} at^2$$ where $$v_{y0} = 0$$ and a= acceleraction due to gravity = $ 9.8 \frac{m}{s^2}$. Therefore we can write that height = dy =$ \frac{1}{2}(9.8)(0.25)^2$= .6125m = 612.5 mm$

To calculate the horizontal distance is more difficult. You don't know the initial velocity of the projectile. But you can determine the initial velocity in the y-direction from the equations. And you know that $v_0 cos(\theta)= V_{y0}$. All of this assumes no friction or drag due to the atmosphere so you'd half to add that to this which will change your equations of motion.

For more info on this you can google the term "physics equations of motion" or ask questions to this group.

Currently, in baseball, they use high-speed doppler radar to track the baseball throughout its trajectory. You can learn more about this by googling Statcast.

Comment: This answer does not give me any new information. I was looking for a precise measurement technique. From paintball and airsoft I know that the trajectory deviates from the model. The ball can randomly go left and right in the air. Only statcast information is interesting for me.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your question.